# How to get both exit code and standard output?

Tags: shell, stdout, exit-code

In shell, such as Bash and Zsh, we can get the **standard output** of a command using `info=$(<command>)`. For example:

```sh
info=$(./run-a-program arg1 arg2)
```

And we can also get the **exit code** from `$?`. It is useful for some command like `timeout`. For example:

```sh
# run the program in 10 seconds
timeout 10s ./run-a-program arg1 arg2
if (( $? == 124 )) {
  echo "Timeout!"
}
```

So is there a way to get both exit code and standard output **at the same time**?

Answer (score 4):

You can still use `$?`:

```
info=$(./run-a-program arg1 arg2)
echo "run-a-program returned $?"
```

But note that you rarely actually need to reference `$?` directly.  Perhaps you want to write code like:

```
info=$(./run-a-program)
if [ $? = 0 ]; then ...; fi
```

But that can be better written as:

```
if info=$(./run-a-program); then ...; fi
```

Sometimes, special return codes other than zero/non-zero are used and you may need to do `case $? in`, but that is about the only time you need to explicitly refer to `$?`. Get out of the habit of looking into `$?`; code is easier to maintain if you don't.